# Testing if value is in list/array (Ti-Basic)

Tags: arrays, list, ti-basic

Is there a way to test if a value is in a list?
In Python, I think you can do something like
 'if n in myList: 
print("Value N is in the list.")'

I don't want to use a for loop to check each value seperately, unless it's the only option.
I'm using a Ti-84 Plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work assuming I've thought through it correctly. It's very simple, where `L₁` is the list to search and `X` is the value to look for.

```
max(not(L₁-X
```

Step-by-step analysis:

1. `L₁-X`: Subtract the value from everything in the list. Now, if this list contains a zero, it means our value was in `L₁`.
2. `not(L₁-X`: Invert everything in the list. This converts all zeroes to ones, and everything else to zeroes. Now, if this list contains a one, it means our value was in `L₁`. If the list is all zeroes, it was not.
3. `max(not(L₁-X`: Get the maximum value in the list. As stated above, the list will be all zeroes if the value was not inside `L₁`, so the maximum value will be zero. If `L₁` had the value inside, the maximum will be a one.

This makes a check as simple as this:

```
If max(not(L₁-X
Disp "The value was found:",X
```

Comment: Wow, this is even cleaner than my solution. Nice!

Comment: You can also use `sum(not(L₁-X` to get the total occurrences. This means you could use it in an if statement like `If sum(not(L₁-X`.

Answer (score 2):

This idea for searching is from [TI-Basic Developer](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/deleted:68k:list-search), and is quite brilliant:

Let's suppose you have a value named `x` and a list named `L`.

```
:If max(1/(1+(abs(L-x))))=1
:Then
//value is in list
:Else
//value is not in list
:End
```

And that's it!

Here is how it works:

`abs(L-x)`

- Firstly, it **subtracts** the searched number from every value of a list and gets its **absolute value**.

`max(1/(1+(abs(L-x))))`

- After that, it **searches for the largest element** in it, **adds it to 1** and **divides 1 by it**.

`:If max(1/(1+(abs(L-x))))=1`

- If it's 1, than the value is **in the list**. Why? Because `1 / 1 + 0` is 1 (a number minus itself is always 0) and 0 is the maximum possible value for `1 / 1 + x` (for positive numbers, of course). If the maximum is smaller than 1, it's **certain** that the searched value is not inside the list.